# How to delete 'orphaned' records from second table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to delete records from a table if the corresponding record is not present in another table.

I.e. table1 has one-to-many relationship with table2. I need to delete orphaned records from table2 where table2.id is not present in table1.

I have tried this in Access:

`DELETE *
FROM t2 
RIGHT JOIN t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id is NULL`

but I get "Syntax error in JOIN operation". I cannot see what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `*` after `DELETE`..

I would have solved it like this:

```
DELETE FROM t2
WHERE id not in (
   SELECT id from t1);
```

Not sure if deleting with a join will work. It would need to be a `LEFT JOIN`though, as you want to delete all the rows in the first part of the join that is not joined with anything. Also, you are joining t2 with itself, guessing it's just a typo..

Comment: I am not sure that Access knows what to do with this.

Comment: Ah, no, the * was necessary. Thanks :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database provider you are using, makes it easier to answer (quite a few differences between the different ones..) So in your case it would be Access..

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

```
DELETE 
from t2
FROM t1 
RIGHT JOIN t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need as @Elizabeth and I found that @Tobb's method worked...but was slow as molasses, taking about a minute to execute on my table.  I found that the following sequence of SQL commands accomplishes the same result in under one second:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD COLUMN [USED] YESNO;
UPDATE t2 SET [USED]=true WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t1);
DELETE FROM t2 WHERE [USED] <> true;
ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN [USED];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no * in **DELETE** statement, so change it like this:

```
DELETE
FROM t2 
WHERE id not in (SELECT id FROM t1)
```

Comment: Access keeps adding t2.* after DELETE. Actually it keeps messing up my whole query. But this does nothing for the syntax error.