# Deleting Orphan Records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a table (say Table1) whose primary key is having foreign key relationship with 10 other tables. All these tables have millions of data. I would need to delete all the orphan records from Table1 in a performance effective manner. Also, the script should not block an writes to these tables. Can somebody help me with the query

I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: I am looking for a more performance optimized script

Comment: You could consider `DELETE CASCADE` relationships in the future.  This would allow you to delete from `Table1` without removing the "10 other tables" data first.  The delete on the primary would then propagate through the related tables, removing the rows referenced by the deleted primary rows from `Table1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete 'orphaned' records from second table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963398/how-to-delete-orphaned-records-from-second-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am trying now:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @totalcnt INT
        ,@Batch INT = 1000

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMPWrk') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMPWrk

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP (TableKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE #TEMPWrk (TableKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT
    A.TableKey
FROM
    dbo.Table1 A
        LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table2 UNION
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table3 UNION
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table4 UNION
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table5 UNION
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table6 UNION
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table7 UNION
                    SELECT TableKey FROM dbo.Table8
                    ) T ON T.TableKey = A.TableKey
WHERE
    T.TableKey IS NULL


SELECT 
    @totalcnt = COUNT(*)
FROM
    #TEMP

WHILE (@totalcnt > 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT @totalcnt
    DELETE TOP (@batch)
    FROM
        #TEMP
    OUTPUT DELETED.TableKey INTO #TEMPWrk   

    DELETE T
    FROM
        dbo.Table1 T
            JOIN #TEMPWrk A ON T.TableKey = A.TableKey

    DELETE FROM #TEMPWrk

    SELECT 
        @totalcnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM
        #TEMP
END

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

I did similar deletes as below:

1. Identify clustered Index Key on the deleting table and delete in batches of 10k to 100k based on the hardware scenario.
2. If you have triggers, CT, CDC, Indexed Views on those tables, then we need to drop or disable during the delete which will make deletes faster.
3. I made 'Recovery Mode' to SIMPLE during delete operation.
4. Called explicit 'Checkpoint' during some batches of deletes.

For any given scenario if you are not allowed to do any of the above steps in PROD then online delete will be slower respectively

Answer (score 0):

As there are transactions in both tables and to minimize locking, you can apply the principle **Divide and conquer**

1- get the max id of table 1 (the parent table)

2- run the following script in stages, e.g 100000 row per iteration

```
DELETE FROM tabl2  t2
WHERE  t2.id  < 100000
AND    t2.id  IN (SELECT t1.id FROM table1 t1)
```

3- repeat step2 for other range

```
    where  t2.id BETWEEN  100001 AND 200000
```

up to max id

You can automate these steps using while statement